# Erro ao criar uma validação customizada em ASPNET MVC ( Client Side )

Tags: asp.net, mvc, validação, dataannotations

Estou com um problema ao criar uma validação customizada usando dataanotations pelo aspnet mvc.

**Minha Model:**

```
    public class Usuario
    {

        public string Nome { get; set; }


        [Idade(18)]   
        public string Senha { get; set; }
     }
```

Minha Classe de Validação:

```
    public class Idade : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly int _idade;
        public Idade(int idade)
        {
            _idade = idade;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {

            if(value != null)
            {
                var idadeInformada = _idade;

                if (idadeInformada <= 18) {

                    return new ValidationResult(null);

                }
                else
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("Você não possui idade suficiente para se cadastrar");
                }
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

O grande problema é que não está funcionado essa validação customizada, quando dou um ***POST*** na página ele não exibe o erro da validação, diferente de quando coloco as validações ***"nativas"*** do ***dataannotations***

Answer (score 0):

A sua lógica está um pouco equivocada, você não está comparando o valor com o filtro declarado e a condição está invertida.

```
public class Idade : ValidationAttribute
{
    private int _idadeMinima;
    public Idade(int idadeMinima)
    {
        _idadeMinima = idadeMinima;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        if (value != null)
        {
            var idadeInformada = int.Parse(value.ToString());

            if (idadeInformada < _idadeMinima)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Você não possui idade suficiente para se cadastrar");
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
     }
}
```

Assim como você deve preparar a sua view para exibir a mensagem de erro e devolver a model para ela após a validação do post na controller.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Idade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Idade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Idade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: realmente a lógica estava errado, porém o erro persiste, a mensagem não aparece.

Comment: A sua view está preparada para isso? Você está devolvendo a ViewModel para ela após o post?

Comment: dando uma pesquisada mais afundo vi que tem tem que ser criado um jquery.unobtrusive, é isso mesmo?

Comment: @William Conseguiu?

Comment: Do seu jeito ainda não consegui, fiz um teste estendendo o jquery validate e funcionou mais ou menos.